# How to get Doxygen 1.8 features in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, doxygen

So I'm trying to fully embrace Doxygen in Xcode (11.1).

According to the Doxygen documentation, features like [Markdown](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/markdown.html) and [Lists](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/lists.html) should be supported in Doxygen 1.8.0 and later.

If I run the `doxygen --version` command it tells me I have version **1.8.3**.

But when I try to use Markdown, lists, and similar features in my Objective-C Doxygen comments, Xcode's built-in documentation generator seems to ignore them.

What am I missing? Is there a magic project setting or Doxygen configuration file I have to set/tweak?

Update: Here's an example that I think should work, but doesn't.

```
/** Called for each `DirectoryPackage` read during `buildSessions`
 *
 * Base class performs the final verification of the package references and adds all of the directory and file package
 * references to the session. Specifically:
 *    - ensures immediate file references are in this session
 *    - checks that all delta file and directory references are correctly inherited
 *    - performs session package reference accounting
 * @param info session details
 * @param directoryPackage the directory package
 * @param inheritedPackageSet package numbers belonging to inherited layers
 * @throws verify or inheritance exception
 */
```

And here's how this get formatted in Xcode:
[image]

Comment: Doxygen version 1.8.3 is from December 2012, the current version is 1.8.18 so I would anyway update your doxygen version (Note: I don't know how these doxygen features are used in XCode, so I don't know whether te doxyge update alone is sufficient).

Comment: @Albert, while it's generally great the have the latest version, that doesn't address the issue. I didn't install Doxygen (I suspect Xcode did) and I should already have the features I want to use.

Comment: The reference to the markdown and lists is made to the most recent documentation (though these features should be available in 1.8.3 as well). Furthermore features might have had bugs that ave been fixed in recent versions. Best is to give a small code example that shows what it is not working in doxygen (together with the changes to the doxygen configuration file).

Comment: Lists don't work (-# ignored). Markdown characters are ignored (\`, \*, \*\*, \_, \_\_ all ignored and render as literal characters). Markdown lists are ignored (1., *, ...). This is not simply some obscure incompatibility between 1.8.3 and 1.8.18.

Comment: The literal characters might give a clue, are there 4 spaces in front of the line? I did a quick text with 1.8.3 but I saw for `-# item` the correct result, so I think an example / MWE would be nice. There might be a difference (and is between the 1.8.3 output for Xcode and the 1.8.18 version, but this is something I cannot judge. I'm using HTML as reference).

Comment: Added example with result

Comment: Pity that the function definition isn't in the example.

Comment: The method's definition in code is *exactly* as it appears in the __Declaration__ section. ;)

Comment: Yes but it doesn't cut and paste from an image.

Answer (score 0):

As I want to add some images it doesn't fit in a comment.

It looks like that the basic information is present in the 1.8.18 and 1.8.3 HTML files.

[image]

It looks like that XCode cannot translate `<ul>` / `<li>` elements.

Comment: Xcode's HTML documentation renderer does support lists, as can be evidenced by pulling up the pop-up documentation for the `NSCopying` protocol, among others. And also note that the Markdown wasn't rendered either. So this isn't a limitation of the Xcode documentation UI.

Comment: Sidebar: It's not like Xcode has its own HTML renderer. I'm sure it uses the standard WebKit view, which fully supports all modern HTML/CSS/JavaScript.